# ElasticSearch Website search autocomplete feature behavior

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to replicate the exact behavior of the search feature on the [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/) website.

Does anybody know where I can find the source of the mappings/settings? And how the query is performed?

**Main Requirements:**

- All searchs must be case insensitive(lets use the "lowercase" TokenFilter).
- Matched search query should be highlighted(check the bold parts on the outputs below).
- The order of the results matter, basically the "phrases" with less characters that match the search query should be returned first, in order to return exact(or near) matches first.

**Scenario**

Imagine I have the following dataset:

```
ID, NAME
1,  SoftwareRocks everytime 
10, The is nothing like home
8,  Opacc Software AG is good but software is even better 
2,  Opacc Software AG 
3,  Sage KHK Software AG 
4,  Software AG 
5,  bbv Software Services AG 
6,  Software AG2 
7,  Sof on the world
```

**Test 1**

**Input**: sof

**Output**:

- 4,  **Sof**tware AG
- 6,  **Sof**tware AG2
- 7,  **Sof** on the world
- 2,  Opacc **Sof**tware AG
- 3,  Sage KHK **Sof**tware AG
- 1,  **Sof**twareRocks everytime
- 5,  bbv **Sof**tware Services AG
- 8,  Opacc **Sof**tware AG is good but **sof**tware is even better

**Test 2**

**Input**: soft

**Output**:

- 4,  **Sof**tware AG
- 6,  **Sof**tware AG2
- 2,  Opacc **Sof**tware AG
- 3,  Sage KHK **Sof**tware AG
- 1,  **Soft**wareRocks everytime
- 5,  bbv **Sof**tware Services AG
- 8,  Opacc **Sof**tware AG is good but **soft**ware is even better

**Test 3**

**Input**: software

**Output**:

- 4,  **Software** AG
- 6,  **Software** AG2
- 2,  Opacc **Software** AG
- 3,  Sage KHK **Software** AG
- 1,  **Software**Rocks everytime
- 5,  bbv **Software** Services AG
- 8,  Opacc **Software** AG is good but **software** is even better

**Test 4**

**Input**: software ag

**Output**:

- 4,  **Software AG**
- 6,  **Software AG**2
- 2,  Opacc **Software AG**
- 3,  Sage KHK **Software AG**
- 8,  Opacc **Software AG** is good but software is even better

**Try 1**

```
PUT /my_index
    {
        "settings": { 
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "autocomplete_filter": { 
                        "type":     "edge_ngram",
                        "min_gram": 1,
                        "max_gram": 20
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "autocomplete": {
                        "type":      "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "autocomplete_filter" 
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

PUT /my_index/_mapping/my_type
    {
    "type": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type":            "string",
                "analyzer":  "autocomplete", 
                "search_analyzer": "standard" 
            }
        }
    }

GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "software"
        }
    }
}
```

**Try 2**

```
{"query" : {"match_phrase_prefix": { "name": "Software ag" }}}
```

This returns properly, but the highlight seems off. For instance:

- 4,  **Software AG**
- 6,  **Software AG2**
- 2,  Opacc **Software AG**
- 3,  Sage KHK **Software AG**
- 8,  Opacc **Software AG** is good but software is even better

What I expect is the search term to be hightlighted. And the order of the returned elements should be based on the length of the full term.

Comment: i can help you with that if you can post some more info regarding your usecase. try adding document structure/data model or try uploading a sample data.

Comment: @user3775217 i updated the question and added a dataset and a few expected results. Can you take a look? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. This will hightlight search results.

```
{
    'query':{
        'filtered':{
            'query':{
                'match':{
                    '_all':{
                        'query':"soft",
                        'type':'phrase'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    'highlight':{
        'pre_tags':'<em>',
        'post_tags':'</em>',
        'fields':{'*':{}}
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Basically it will only match the exact phrase. If I search for "soft" none of the results is returned.

Answer (score 0):

ok, your use case is pretty simple. The autocomplete on on elastic website is also quite straight forward use case of autocomplete, but they have the search data set structured over multiple fields and also matched keyword from the field also determine the relevance/order for the search result.

For you to keep things simple i would go with [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) for the string in the mappings and do simple filtered search
Mappings

```
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {           
            "autocomplete_analyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "asciifolding", "filter_ngram"]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "filter_stop": {
                "type": "stop",
                "stopwords": "_english_",
                "ignore_case": true
            },
            "filter_shingle": {
                "type": "shingle",
                "max_shingle_size": 2,
                "min_shingle_size": 2,
                "output_unigrams": true
            },
            "filter_snowball": {
                "type": "snowball",
                "language": "english"
            },
            "filter_stemmer": {
                "type": "porter_stem",
                "language": "English"
            },
            "filter_ngram": {
                "type": "nGram",
                "min_gram": 3,
                "max_gram": 15
            },
            "filter_edgengram": {
                "type": "edgeNGram",
                "min_gram": 2,
                "max_gram": 15
            },
            "filter_worddelimiter": {
                "type": "word_delimiter"
            }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
            "haystack_ngram_tokenizer": {
                "type": "nGram",
                "min_gram": 3,
                "max_gram": 15
            },
            "haystack_edgengram_tokenizer": {
                "type": "edgeNGram",
                "min_gram": 2,
                "max_gram": 15,
                "side": "front"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These mappings also include some advanced filters that i have used in my autcomplete solutions.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "FIELD": "VALUE"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The example on elastic don't do [spell-check/fuzzy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) query for the keyword entered.

If you want to add fuzzy also then you also look at above documentation to build a fuzzy query according to your usecase and tune fuzziness.

Comment: This does not work. Can you provide a real "implementation"?

Comment: what doesn't work, would you care to add more details like the errors, logs or something. I suppose you are beginner here for elastic, if that is the case refer these links https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html and https://jontai.me/blog/2013/02/adding-autocomplete-to-an-elasticsearch-search-application/

Comment: I updated my question with 2 implementations. One is based on the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html . However the highlight parts seem off. If I search by "software ag" I expect only that "software ag" be highlighted and not "software ag2" for instance.